# Chart js is it possible to assign space between the legend and the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Iam using Chart.js and have a simple question.

Is it possible to assign a attribute like margin onto the legend property of the chart.js options?

This is my chart.js optionsObject:

```
optionsObject = {
                legend: {
                    margin: {
                        bottom: 40,
                        // top: 40
                    },
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'center',
                    padding: 40,
                    labels: {
                        padding: 30,
                        boxWidth: 30,

                        fontSize: 15,
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: false,
                    datasource: {
                        url: 'sample-dataset.csv'
                    }
                },

                responsive: true,
                // without maintainAspectRatio all Charts crash height!!!!!!!
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        id: 'X',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Date'
                        },
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        id: 'Y',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: '# Bravos'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: function (value) {
                                if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                            },
                            stepSize: 1
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
```

This is my actual output of the chart: [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKbZP.png)

My goal is to move up the legend section so the chart have more space between legend and chart data. I am pretty new to Chart.js and hope u can help me.

Thanks in advance.